# How create list tags in a page with image and count post

Tags: wordpress, tags

I created a list of categories in a page. The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<div style="margin:0 0 10px 10px; border: 1px solid #888; float: left; padding:1px; text-align:center;"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"><img src="https://arsipkoran.ga/img/logo/koran-thumb/thumb-' . $category->cat_name . '.png" alt="' . $category->cat_name . '" style="width:180px;height:30px;" /><br/>' . $category->name . '</a><br/> (' . $category->category_count . ' arsip)</div>';
}
?>
```

The results are as successful as the following links: https://pustakakoran.com/direktori-e-koran/

Then I try to apply to the tag, the code as follows:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
  );
$tags = get_the_tags( $args );
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    echo '<div style="margin:0 0 10px 10px; border: 1px solid #888; float: left; padding:1px; text-align:center;"><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '"><img src="https://arsipkoran.ga/img/logo/koran-thumb/thumb-' . $tag->name . '.png" alt="' . $tag->name . '" style="width:180px;height:30px;" /><br/>' . $tag->name . '</a><br/> (' . $tag->tag_count . ' kitab)</div>';
}
?>
```

But the result can not. Can anyone help me, which part of the code should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_tags()` and not `get_the_tags()`.

> which part of the code should be fixed

(1) Replace this:

```
$tags = get_the_tags( $args );
```

..with this:

```
$tags = get_tags( $args );
```

(2) Replace this:

```
$tag->tag_count
```

..with this:

```
$tag->count
```

Comment: Thank to Sally. My problem is solved. 
I have applied in my website and success, http://pustakaalwadi.com/penerbit/